# StackOverflowError from recursive function

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm trying to make the maze generator from the game Pengo in java and I have some troubles.

I have a class "Cellule" which means Cell in english (sorry I'm french and I didn't think to ask questions to you guys)

```
public class Cellule{
    int x;
    int y;
    int val;

    public Cellule(int x,int y,int val)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.val=val;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

}
```

Then I have a class "Plateau" which means board which contains my cell tab and all the functions to initialise and generate the maze

```
public class Plateau {
Cellule[][] tab;
int m,n; //doivent etre des nombres impaires/ must be odd numbers
Cellule curPosVer;
Cellule curPosGen;
int verifX;
int verifY;

public Plateau(int m, int n){
    if(m%2==1 && n%2==1){
        this.tab = new Cellule[m][n];
        this.m=m;
        this.n=n;
        this.curPosGen=new Cellule(m-1,0,9);
        this.curPosVer=new Cellule(m-1,0,9);
        this.verifX=0;
        this.verifY=0;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Les nombre m et n doivent etre des nombres impaires");
    }
}

void initPlateau(){
    for(int i=0;i<this.m;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<this.n;j++){
            this.tab[i][j]=new Cellule(i,j,1);
        }
    }
    this.tab[m-1][0].setVal(0);
}

void affichePlateau(){
    System.out.println("Test");
     for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            System.out.print(this.tab[i][j].getVal()+" ");
        }
         System.out.println("");
    }
}

/*void pathFinder(){ //cherche un chemin à partir de curCellVer    
      if(this.tab[this.curPosVer.getX()-2][this.curPosVer.getY()].getVal()==0){
          if(this.tab[this.curPosVer.getX()][this.curPosVer.getY()+2].getVal()==0){

          }
      }
}*/

void pathGen(){ //genere un chemin à partir de curPosGen/ generate a path from curPosGen
    int dir;

    while((this.curPosGen.getX()+2<=m-1)&&(this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()+2][this.curPosGen.getY()].getVal()==1)  ||
          (this.curPosGen.getX()-2>=0)&&(this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()-2][this.curPosGen.getY()].getVal()==1)  ||
          (this.curPosGen.getY()+2<=n-1)&&(this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()][this.curPosGen.getY()+2].getVal()==1)  ||
          (this.curPosGen.getY()-2>=0)&&(this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()][this.curPosGen.getY()-2].getVal()==1)){

        dir=(int)(Math.random()*4);


        switch(dir){
            case 0://Nord
            {
                if(this.curPosGen.getX()-2>=0){
                    if(this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()-2][this.curPosGen.getY()].getVal()==1){
                        this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()-1][this.curPosGen.getY()].setVal(0);
                        this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()-2][this.curPosGen.getY()].setVal(0);
                        this.curPosGen.setX(this.curPosGen.getX()-2);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

            case 1://Est
            {
                if(this.curPosGen.getY()+2<=this.n){
                    if(this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()][this.curPosGen.getY()+2].getVal()==1){
                        this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()][this.curPosGen.getY()+1].setVal(0);
                        this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()][this.curPosGen.getY()+2].setVal(0);
                        this.curPosGen.setY(this.curPosGen.getY()+2);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

            case 2://Sud
            {
                if(this.curPosGen.getX()+2<=this.m-1){
                    if(this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()+2][this.curPosGen.getY()].getVal()==1){
                        this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()+1][this.curPosGen.getY()].setVal(0);
                        this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()+2][this.curPosGen.getY()].setVal(0);
                        this.curPosGen.setX(this.curPosGen.getX()+2);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

            case 3://Ouest
            {
                if(this.curPosGen.getY()-2>0){
                    if(this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()][this.curPosGen.getY()-2].getVal()==1){
                        this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()][this.curPosGen.getY()-1].setVal(0);
                        this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()][this.curPosGen.getY()-2].setVal(0);
                        this.curPosGen.setY(this.curPosGen.getY()-2);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        this.pathGen();
    }
}
}
```

The recursive function which causes the problem is `pathGen()`

Finally, my main looks like this

```
public class TestMain {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Plateau p=new Plateau(13,15);
    p.initPlateau();
    p.affichePlateau();
    p.pathGen();
    p.affichePlateau();
}
}
```

It returns me something like this about 1/10 times

[image: java errors]

It would be awesome if you could help me! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I don't get the complete meaning of your code but as stated by the exception, you are exceeding the capacity of the invocation stack with recursive calls to pathGen.

Why do you need recursion in this case? You have already defined the condition for ending in the while clause

```
 while((this.curPosGen.getX()+2<=m-1)&&(this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()+2][this.curPosGen.getY()].getVal()==1)  ||
      (this.curPosGen.getX()-2>=0)&&(this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()-2][this.curPosGen.getY()].getVal()==1)  ||
      (this.curPosGen.getY()+2<=n-1)&&(this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()][this.curPosGen.getY()+2].getVal()==1)  ||
      (this.curPosGen.getY()-2>=0)&&(this.tab[this.curPosGen.getX()][this.curPosGen.getY()-2].getVal()==1)){
```

just keep on iterating, without invoking another pathGen().

Comment: Thanks, I remove the pathGen() at the end and it worked, but it still makes an infinite loop sometime. Sorry, I'm quite new to java.

Comment: Maybe there is no solution for the maze. Add a maximum number of movements to the while condition.

Comment: I don't get it, my conditions deal with all the cases, it shouldn't loop like that.

Comment: Are you sure that the cell can not repeat a set of movements? I'm in doubt.

Comment: The condition in the while loop checks if the cell we look at is in "tab" (not avoid an OutOfBounds Exception) and then if the cell we look at is a wall(val=1) or a path(val=0). It means that it checks if the current cell (curPosGen) is blocked or not.

Comment: That means that you are checking that the movement is correct. But are you controlling that the cursor do not enter a loop? Making a step to east, back to west, east, west, ... It can happen, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an `stackoverflow` because the method `void pathGen()` is not properly developed...

lets take a look:

```
void pathGen(){ //genere un chemin à partir de curPosGen/ generate a path from curPosGen
    int dir;
while (...) {
    dir = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
    switch (dir) {
    case 0:// Nord
        ...
        break;
    case 1:// Est
        .dir..
        break;
    case 2:// Sud
        ...
        break;
    case 3:// Ouest
        ...
        break;
    }
    this.pathGen();
}
```

as you see,  at the end of the method you have this:
`this.pathGen();` which is nesting you in a deep recursion-call on the method over and over again, so the application is entering in that method and going some kind of infinite recursion that is throwing the exception

remove that and redesign again the logic that keeps you in the while loop

Comment: Thank you for your advices, I'll try it!